# LINQ JOIN with multiple conditions returning error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, join

I have looked through various Q & A for this situation but my error is still persisting.

I have the following:

```
Int32 eid = Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlPrograms.SelectedItem.Value);
var participants =
    from b in _dc.WebProgramParticipants
    join d in _dc.webeventaffiliations
        on new { b.UserID, eid } equals new { d.userid, d.eventid }
    join c in _dc.WebPersonalInfos
        on b.UserID equals c.UserID
    where (b.eventid == eid) select
    new { b.ParticipantID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email, d.institution };
```

Types for the join in question {b.UserID = int, b.eventid = int?} and the equals {d.userid = int, d.eventid = int}

The error of "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'." will not go away. It is saying that the first join has type issues, but the only issue there was was that b.eventid was a nullable which I thought including the eid variable instead would work but it did not.

What is going on with this?

Comment: What types are on each side?

Comment: It looks like the type of `b.UserID` isn't the same as that of `d.userid`, and/or the same for `eid` and `d.eventid`, and as a result the anonymous objects have different types.

Comment: all of the ID's are of type int. I had to create the variable eid to compensate for the Nullable type b.eventid

Comment: @cdhowie, your comment made me look at it from a different perspective, its not the type that was the issue it was the matching of the actual words.

Comment: @mattgcon You could have also just added the following cast instead: `(int?)d.eventid`

Comment: @mattgcon Ah, yes, I forgot about that particular detail about anonymous types.  Gotchas like that are one of the primary reasons I try to avoid them.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by the following

```
var participants = from b in _dc.WebProgramParticipants join d in _dc.webeventaffiliations on new { UserID = b.UserID, eventid = eid } equals new { UserID = d.userid, eventid = d.eventid } join c in _dc.WebPersonalInfos on b.UserID equals c.UserID where (b.eventid == eid) select new { b.ParticipantID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email, d.institution };
```

Ensure that types on both sides of the join conditions have the same Case. (for C# anyway)